# Script to fill fields in a table based on another field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Spool and there's a field named "NAME". This field have a string with 7 values separeted by dashes.

I must do a script in SQL Server that split the string "NAME" by the dashes and record every of the seven values in 7 different columns.

For example
NAME: abcd-0123-asd
In the column1 must record abcd, in column2: 0123 and column3 asd.. etc
I hope i have explained =)

Thanks!!

I'm using SQL 2008, also in my real problem i have 7 segments in my string "NAME" and i have to put every segment of that field in 7 columns.

Also i have n number of records in the table wich apply that script =)
Thanks for you help

---

HI John Dewey I make this:

```
Create FUNCTION  [dbo].[SPReturnThreeFields] ( @str NVARCHAR(max), @delimiter NCHAR(1) )

AS
BEGIN
    declare @strOriginal NVARCHAR(max), @f1 varchar(max), @f2 varchar(max), @f3 varchar(max), @f4 varchar(max),@f5 varchar(max),@f6 varchar(max),@f7 varchar(max), @bool int = 0;

    -- Field 1
    set @f1=(left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));
    SET @str=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    -- Field 2
    set @f2=(left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));
    SET @str=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    -- Field 3
    set @f3 = (left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));
    SET @str=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    set @f4 = (left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));
    SET @str=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    set @f5 = (left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));

    set @bool = case when patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @str) <> 0 then 0 else 1 end;
    SET @str= case when @bool = 0 then RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)) else @str end;    

    set @f6 = case when patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @str) < 1 then case when @bool = 0 then @str else '' end else (left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1)) end;   

    set @bool = case when patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @str) <> 0 then 0 else 1 end;
    SET @str= case when @bool = 0 then RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)) else @str end;        

    set @f7 = case when patindex('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @str) < 1 then case when @bool = 0 then @str else '' end else (left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1)) end;   

    --update dbo.Spool SET Segmento1 = @f1,Segmento2 = @f2,Segmento3 = @f3,Segmento4 = @f4, Segmento5 = @f5, Segmento6 = @f6, Segmento7 = @f7 where Nombre = @strOriginal;

END

GO
```

Apparently it works fine but what if i want to make the update in the same table, how you call the function or must be a store procedure?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also please specify the version of SQL Server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't strictly need a CTE, but it keeps the number of SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX/etc. calculations to a minimum.

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        Name,
        fdash = CHARINDEX('-', Name),
        ldash = CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Name)),
        slen = LEN(Name)
    FROM dbo.Spool
    -- WHERE clause goes here
)
INSERT dbo.OtherTable(Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT 
    Column1 = LEFT(Name, fdash - 1),
    Column2 = SUBSTRING(Name, fdash + 1, slen - fdash - ldash),
    Column3 = RIGHT(Name, ldash - 1)
FROM x;
```

This assumes that every value has two dashes. If you can't guarantee that (e.g. it is not enforced with a constraint), you should either put a where clause on the above, or define what you want to do if there are 0, 1, or > 2 dashes. The where clause would be:

```
WHERE LEN(Name) - LEN(REPLACE(Name, '-', '')) = 2
```

Comment: This work fine with 2 dashes but what if there are more dashes? i have 6 dashes as maximum and i have the 7 columns in the same table and i have to fill this columns if there are segments in the field Name. Also can be the possibility that not all the columns can be filled
Thank you so much for the help! =)

Answer (score 0):

This table-valued function will allow various delimiters.

Compatibility is SQL 2005+

```
----------------------------------------
-- Define function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnReturnThreeFields ( @str NVARCHAR(max), @delimiter NCHAR(1) )
RETURNS @retval TABLE(Field1 NVARCHAR(max), Field2 NVARCHAR(max), Field3 NVARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN
    declare @f1 varchar(max), @f2 varchar(max), @f3 varchar(max);

    -- Field 1
    set @f1=(left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));
    SET @str=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    -- Field 2
    set @f2=(left(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1)-1));

    -- Field 3
    SET @f3=RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str,1));

    insert into @retval values (@f1,@f2,@f3);

    RETURN;
END
GO

----------------------------------------
-- define test tables
declare @table1 table(Name NVARCHAR(max));
declare @table2 table(Field1 NVARCHAR(max), Field2 NVARCHAR(max), Field3 NVARCHAR(max));
insert into @table1 values ('one-two-three')
, ('four-five-six')
, ('seven-eight-nine');

----------------------------------------
-- load parsed values into @table2, from @table1
insert into @table2
select p.* 
from @table1 t
cross apply dbo.fnReturnThreeFields(t.Name,'-') p

----------------------------------------
-- see the results
select * from @table2;
GO
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That returns them as rows, but the user wants them inserted into three separate columns. Also you shouldn't declare `NCHAR` without length - is that `NCHAR(1)` or `NCHAR(30)`? As an aside the while loop method for splitting strings is kind of a performance hog as you get into the higher end of values - see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand
Thx, I guess I misread the column definitions; the corrected solution is posted.

Comment: And here is why `NCHAR` without length is a bad idea: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand
Good article. I expect default len=1 except cast and convert, where len=30. Are there any other contexts where if would default to 30?
Anyway, the parameter is now an explicit (1). Thx